# Magento 2.3.5 - Display block on product page only if product got related products

Tags: related-products, magento2.3.5

On our productpage we want to display a block, only if that product got related products.

How can I check in M2 if the product got related products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step - 1**
Override the **catalog_product_view.xml** layout into your theme or your module and call this block.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="blockname"  template="Vendor_ModuleName::blockname.phtml"/>
```

**Step- 2**

Now Create the **blockname.phtml** into the view\frontend\templates\ directory and write down the below code

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>

<?php 
$relatedProductIds = $_product->getRelatedProductIds(); 
//checke product have related product or not
if (!empty($relatedProductIds)) {
    //call the block here...
}

?>
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**

Comment: Thanks, works perfect!